# "No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?" using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

this is the code that is generating the error, the fullfillment response generated by this intent upon being called is "No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?" what should i do to correct it?

```
app.intent('getCrypto', (conv,{crypto="ethereum",cryptoactions="price"}) =>{
     fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/').then(response => {
       return response.json();
     }).then(data => {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            if (data[i].id === "bitcoin")
               conv.data.price=data[i].price_usd;
               conv.ask(`${conv.data.price} is the current value of ${crypto}`);
               return response.json();
          }

     }).catch(err => {
          return conv.ask(`${cryptoactions} of ${crypto} is not available. Would you like to know about another one?`);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message describes the exact issue "Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?"

You should return an async call from your intent handler. So, adding a `return` right before your call to `fetch` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this issue in [Dialogflow API version 2](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/migration-points-for-upgrading-to-actions-on-google-nodejs-version-2-4640648ab8b5),

You must `return Promise`, would you prefer to use these structures?

```
app.intent('getCrypto', conv => {
    // I - MUST HAVE PROMISE IN HERE
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
            .then(res => {
                ...

                resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

                reject(error)
            });
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);

        // II - MUST HAVE THIS RESPONSE
        // conv.ask(new SimpleResponse("..."));
        conv.close(new SimpleResponse(texts.goodbye));
    }, function (error) {

    });
})
```